# get another user's follower numbers from new (2021) instagram API

Tags: instagram

I like to get an instagram user's followers number. I.e. `https://www.instagram.com/robertdowneyjr` has 50.8 million followers.

First I've tried the simplest way where you get the `https://www.instagram.com/robertdowneyjr/?__a=1` URL and parse followers from the JSON format **but it's only works when you already signed in instagram at current browser** or u'll be redirected to the login page.

I also have instagram API credentials (appId, secret, redirect URL) for the Instagram Basic Display (facebook API product) and I can set up the connection and can use API's endpoints, but with that I'm unable to get a 3rd user's followers number but my own/or the user's who authorized the app (documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/).

So I like to get anyone's followers number only by their instagram username `I.e. robertdowneyjr`. Where would I search for?

Comment: U can use some headless browser to do that. here is a example https://github.com/alimtegar/instagram-bot/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @E-P thank you but it's not really a solution, because it supposes the login page's form elements. Instagram going to ban your IP after a few try. I prefer like to use some API based solution where you don't have to risk any IP ban or similar penalties.

Comment: But you cant do that! thas kind of gray hat and against privacy rules.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: There is no official api to do that, you cant get other users follow nr, they have to login and auth to get there own

Comment: @Roland it is possible to get follower counts from the API for Business and Creator accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is with business discovery API (although it has its problems.  IG API has never fully recovered from their sudden deprecation of the legacy API).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

Refer to the documentation for the necessary permissions.  Here is an example of the call you will need to make:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/xxxx?fields=business_discovery.username(USERNAME){followers_count}&access_token=TOKEN](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/xxxx?fields=business_discovery.username(USERNAME)%7Bfollowers_count%7D&access_token=TOKEN)

WHERE xxxx is the Instagram ID of the account that has the permissions, USERNAME is the instagram username that you are trying to retrieve followers for, and TOKEN is an access_token that has the appropriate permissions.

This will only get followers for business or creator accounts.  Individual accounts will not work, even if they are public.

Comment: I think I have tried that before but got an error message because of limitations u mentioned before. Its very frustrating that legacy API (some still in use) could do the job, no matter what type of account being requested

Comment: most accounts that you would be trying to get the followers for are going to be business or creator, and will work.  I mean businesses or public figures or instagram "influencers".  Regular people generally not.  We have never recovered from the deprecation of the legacy API.  There are still many holes in the replacement, and it is a constant pain in the ass.  There are many things that used to be easy but are now difficult or impossible or subject to severe rate limiting.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a countless number of Instagram data scraping applications for clients... and I'll keep it real with you: stay far, far away from the Facebook Business API. It's atrocious.

What I *do* recommend, is using Instagram's private API that they expose to mobile or their public web-facing API. Luckily for us, people have written many libraries that utilise both of these APIs. Most of these libraries also automatically handle Instagram's rate limiting.

Here are some of the libraries I've used and would recommend:

- Python:  [instagrapi](https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi)
- TypeScript: [instagram-private-api](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api)
- Java: [instagram4j](https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j)
- C#: [InstagramApiSharp](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp)

Comment: Also, I'm incredibly passionate about this because it is just ridiculous how far Instagram/Facebook has gone to make it nearly impossible to scrape their platform. I guess I understand, they want agencies to pay the big bucks for it, but dear god, I've never seen a platform where you literally have to fight to get trivial things like follower counts.

Comment: Yes, the API can be very frustrating, and the IG api is far more so than the FB side.  I suppose if you can count on a third party library to stay updated by someone else, and not find it broken one morning then it could work.  What kind of rate limits will you see using one of the libraries that does handle the rate limiting for you?  With an approved app and a relatively small number of users I can manage several thousand handles  without hitting any limits.

Comment: both @dir and Chris answers were good however Chris pointed at the official API so I'm accepted his solution.

Comment: @dir I am still curious about rate limiting in libraries like instagrapi.  Can you give some insight?